# What is the difference between "global::System" and "System" in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, namespaces

I just upgraded a VS 2005 project to VS 2008 and was examining the changes.  I noticed one of the .Designer.cs files had changed significantly.  The majority of the changes were simply replacements of *System* with *global::System*. For example,

```
protected override System.Data.DataTable CreateInstance()
```

became

```
protected override global::System.Data.DataTable CreateInstance()
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The :: operator is called a Namespace Alias Qualifier.

```
 global::System.Data.DataTable
```

is the same as:

```
 System.Data.DataTable
```

Visual Studio 2008 added it to the designer generated code to avoid ambigious reference issues that occasionally happened when people created classes named System...For example:

```
class TestApp
{
    // Define a new class called 'System' to cause problems.
    public class System { }

    // Define a constant called 'Console' to cause more problems.
    const int Console = 7;
    const int number = 66;

    static void Main()
    {
        // Error  Accesses TestApp.Console
        //Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

However:

```
global::System.Console.Writeline("This works");
```

For further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't get any good hits on google because of the colons, I suppose.  However, there is no custom System class or namespace in this project, so I don't know why it felt the need to fully qualify those System references.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent people from doing [#1 on this list](http://thesoftwarejedi.blogspot.com/2008/05/4-naughty-c-35-code-changes-for-your.html).  :)